# AngularJS: ng-model not clearing input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a dynamic input for CPFs (Brazilian 'social security' number).

Every time I enter one CPF, another input should be displayed, and so on..
But for some reason, the ng-model is not being cleared after the CPF is added.

Here's my HTML (inside a directive with isolate scope):

```
<div ng-repeat="cpf in cpfs" class="field-input">
    <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="cpf.number" required>
    <label>added CPF</label>
</div>
<div class="field-input">
     <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="cpf.number" required>
     <label>add new CPF</label>
     <button ng-click="addCpf(cpf)" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
</div>
```

Here's my controller (inside a directive with isolate scope):

```
$scope.cpfs = [];

$scope.addCpf = function(cpf) {
     $scope.cpfs.push(angular.copy(cpf));     
     delete $scope.cpf;
 };
```

Comment: use $scope.cpf = undefined;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `delete $scope.cpf;` use `$scope.cpf.number = "";`

we can't delete an model, we have to set it to blank, because its linked with our View part

Comment: please add a brief description as to how your solution resolves the askers problem. [answer]

Comment: we can't delete an model, we have to set it to blank, because its linked with our View part